# Auto-tagging of Images uploaded to Picasa-web-albums via Blogger

Tags: blogger, picasa-web-albums

When images are added to a blog post on Blogger using the Post Editor's Add-picture feature, those images are stored in Picasa-web-albums.

Is there a way to get Picasa-web-albums to automatically tag the image, using the labels attached to the blog post that was being edited when the image was loaded?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feature offered by either Blogger or Picasa-web-albums / Google+ Photos. (And I can think of a number of reasons why it would be difficult to add this as a feature to Blogger).

Maybe you could write an ITTTT recipe to apply the tags when you publish a post?   I'm not sure if this is possible, though, because the Blogger post just contains the URL of the photo and no a reference to the album it is in.